# Javascript console returns "ReferenceError: array is undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently a high school student fiddling around with trying to learn how to program, however I am completely dumbfounded by this one problem I am currently encountering.

I am trying to write a small game using the [rot.js libraries](http://ondras.github.io/rot.js/hp/). Specifically, right now I am trying to create a random name generator for certain items. To do this I tried creating multiple arrays of various words where I can randomly select one member of the array and piece them together with other randomly selected words from other arrays to create some vaguely roguelike-y names.

Rot.js [comes with a handy tool](http://ondras.github.io/rot.js/manual/#js) that selects a random member of an array for you. However every time I try to use it, the JavaScript console spits out at me "ReferenceError: swords is undefined". Unfortunately I am 99.99% confident that I have declared my array 'swords' as global so I am completely confounded.

I have googled for an answer, though the solutions provided are either ineffective or are beyond my current understanding of the javascript.

My array is as follows, in a file called words.js:

```js
var swords = new Array();
var swords = ["sabre", "scimitar", "sword", "blade", "katana", "claymore", "gladius", "spatha", "broadsword", "jian", "talwar", "kris", "rapier"];
```

The function whereby I am trying to randomly select one of the words is as follows, in a file called phraseGenerator.js

```js
var weaponGenerate = function() {
  return swords.random(); //swords from swords.js; random() from the ROT.js api
}

console.log(this.weaponGenerate());
```

And finally, the html file I am trying to use to run everything is as follows, in a file called phraseGenerator.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="phraseGenerator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="words.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/rot.js/rot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help or form of explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: which line is throwing the error, can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: The issue almost certainly lies with *where* and how your objects and elements are being created. If you get an error that says `swords is undefined` that means *swords is indeed undefined* within that scope you're trying to access it in. Would you be able to show us where you define swords and where you try to access it which gives you that error?

Comment: Given that you're getting that error, it's a little odd that you'd have 99.9% confidence that the array is declared properly. Also there's no need to initialize a variable with `new Array()` when you immediately re-initialize it with an array literal. Variables are not bound to particular types in JavaScript.

Comment: swap the order of loading `phraseGenerator.js` and `words.js` in `phraseGenerator.html`

Comment: I din't get any error with your code, I got `spatha` as output. @Rajesh, You got that error because you might tested with fiddle. Change the order of scripts.

Comment: @Rajesh - `weaponGenerate` is a global function, `this` in global context is `window` so ...`this.weaponGenerate` in the code as shown is identical to `window.weaponGenerate` so will work just as well

Comment: @JaromandaX, rot.js should be the top one.

Comment: @NK - yes, that too - so it's a complete reversal of order :p - or at least, rot.js before phraseGenerator.js which relies on rot.js

Comment: Ohh wow, of course I would make a mistake as stupid as that. Changing the order of the scripts fixed it. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

**words.js** - re creating array is redundant

```
//removed var swords = new Array(); as you are already creating brand new array below
var swords = ["sabre", "scimitar", "sword", "blade", "katana", "claymore", "gladius", "spatha", "broadsword", "jian", "talwar", "kris", "rapier"];
```

**phraseGenerator.js** - remove `this` keyword as it's not linked to any object/function/environment

```
var weaponGenerate = function() {
  return swords.random(); //swords from swords.js; random() from the ROT.js api
}
console.log(weaponGenerate()); //removed `this` keyword
```

**index.html** - order is important, put `rot.js` first, then `words.js`, and lastly `phaseGenerator.js`, because `rot.js` must extend **Array**'s functionality, so that in generator, array has `random()` method

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="bower_components/rot.js/rot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="words.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="phraseGenerator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Checkout working example below

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ondras/rot.js/master/rot.js"></script>
<script>
  //removed var swords = new Array(); as you are already creating brand new array below
  var swords = ["sabre", "scimitar", "sword", "blade", "katana", "claymore", "gladius", "spatha", "broadsword", "jian", "talwar", "kris", "rapier"];
</script>
<script>
  var weaponGenerate = function() {
    return swords.random(); //swords from swords.js; random() from the ROT.js api
  }
  console.log(weaponGenerate()); //removed `this` keyword
</script>


<button id="button">generated word is <b id="word">EMPTY</b> <em>Click to generate more</em></button>

<script>
  //for demo purpose
  document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector('#word').innerHTML = weaponGenerate();
  }
  button
</script>
```

Comment: No need to remove this keyword, please read discussions under post.

Comment: Yes, it's not required, but it's much cleaner, because if code get's bigger, it will be easy to confuse what __this__ is this

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="bower_components/rot.js/rot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="words.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="phraseGenerator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the order of the scripts. Invoke rot.js first. And yes, `var sword = new Array` is unnecessary, though you won't get an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="bower_components/rot.js/rot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="words.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="phraseGenerator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```